# IRS pre-tax commuter benefits: when does the year begin?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I read on https://www.connectyourcare.com/assets/U133A-Transportation-Benefits.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171204183317/https://www.connectyourcare.com/assets/U133A-Transportation-Benefits.pdf)):

> For tax years beginning after January 1, 2018, the IRS allows up to $260 a month  pre-tax for commuter costs [...].

In 2017, that amount was 255 USD.

Through my employer, I may purchase commuter checks (which qualify for commuter costs) each month via https://www.flexcommute.com. On the website, when ordering commuter checks,  I see today (2017-12-04):

> - Benefit Month: January 2018
> - Order by  Sunday, December 10, 2017

which means I have till Sunday, December 10, 2017 to order commuter checks fo January 2018. However, in practice I sometime receive these commuter checks before January 2018, in which case the validity date may also be before January 2018.

Can I order 255 USD or 260 USD  pre-tax today (2017-12-04)?

Comment: Mostly with taxes, the date of the transaction determines the tax year of the transaction.  Have you used this month's/years' benefit?  If not, put it on this year and shrug away the difference.  The $660 you save in actual taxes due over the year dwarfs the $1 you don't save during this one month.

Comment: @Xalorous Thanks. What is the date of the transaction? When I order the checks? When my bank account is charged for it? When I receive the checks? Some other date?

Comment: The financial transaction I would say occurs when your account is charged.  Of course I'm basing this opinion on common sense, not on tax laws.  LOL.

Comment: @Xalorous Thanks, they can indeed be different :-) let's see if someone has some legal insight.